# Use self-defined XSD to extend XML based on public XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I started out thinking this would be simple, but I'm stuck:

I want to write/read XML files based on a publicly available XSD with a couple of extra elements that I want to define in my own XSD. The XML is principally supposed to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>

<PublicRoot xmlns="http://public.com/PublicSchema" xmlns:own="http://myown.com/OwnSchema">
    <PublicA>
        <PublicB PublicAttrib1="1">
            <!-- I only want own:OwnA to validate OK here, inside the PublicB element: -->
            <own:OwnA OwnAttrib1="My own attribute" />
        </PublicB>
        <own:OwnA OwnAttrib1="My own attribute" /> <!-- Should FAIL validation -->
    </PublicA>
    <own:OwnA OwnAttrib1="My own attribute" /> <!-- Should FAIL validation -->
</PublicRoot>
```

Of course, the public schema allows extra elements from other schemas inside its elements - the following is a part of all elements in the PublicSchema:

```
<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
```

This means that the above XML sample fully validates using the following OwnSchema XSD in addition to the PublicSchema XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://myown.com/OwnSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="OwnA">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="OwnAttrib1" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

My problem is, I want to create an XSD that does NOT validate a correctly formatted Own-element that is placed other places in the tree of Public nodes than I want it to (in my above example, only own:OwnA elements placed as child elements of the PublicB element should be valid).

I have thought about redefining or extending the type of the PublicB element, but that seems to imply tampering with the PublicSchema, that I should not touch.

Am I trying to do something illogical or impossible, or is this possible to solve?

Comment: "the public schema allows extra elements from other schemas inside its elements" - That is, is contains `<xs:any>` elements? So you'd need to validate something that matches `<xs:any>` but not your `OwnA` element at some places?

Comment: The public schema does contain `<xs:any>` elements - I have edited in how this looks in my question text. That only means that to PublicSchema you may add `<own:Anything>` anywhere. What I'm looking for is however for OwnSchema to constrain the use of `<own:OwnA ...>` elements by only allowing it inside the `<PublicB>` elements.